# XAML Bounding Box on Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, maps

I'm doing an app that uses the Microsoft.Maps and I'm having to problems that I hope that you can help me solving. (Taking into account that I'm using C# with MVVM architecture and XAML)

**Q1:** I'm defining the Center position as (0,0) and I'm trying to change it programatically but for some reason before the map is "Loaded" the center doesn't change. How can I do it?

**Q2:** I'm adding my pushpinn and some friends pushpins (their location are given) and I want to focus the map as somekind of boundedbox to focus only myself and my friends. How can I do this keeping the architecture?

**XAML VIEW**

```
<Grid>
    <m:Map x:Name="MyMap" CredentialsProvider="mycredential" Center="{Binding MyCurrentPos}" ZoomLevel="16">
        <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinList}">
            <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding location}" Background="Red"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
```

**C# VIEWMODEL**

```
public OverViewViewModel() {
        MyCurrentPos = "0,0";
        getLocation();
    } 
private ObservableCollection<PushPinHelper> _pushpinList;
    public ObservableCollection<PushPinHelper> PushpinList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pushpinList == null)
            {
                _pushpinList = new ObservableCollection<PushPinHelper>();
            }
            return _pushpinList;

        }
        set { _pushpinList = value; }
    }
  public void getLocation()
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged;
        watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)); // try start
    }

    private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
        PushPinHelper pp = new PushPinHelper(geo.ToString());
        MyCurrentPos = geo.ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("MyCurrentPos");
        PpHelper = pp;
        OnPropertyChanged("PpHelper");
        addMyself(pp);
    }
    public void addMyself(PushPinHelper geo)
    {
        PushpinList.Add(geo);
        OnPropertyChanged("PushpinList");
    }
   private PushPinHelper _ppHelper;
    public PushPinHelper PpHelper
    {
        get { return _ppHelper; }
        set
        {
            _ppHelper = value;
        }
    }
 // CLASS PushpinHelper
 public class PushPinHelper
{
    public PushPinHelper(string loc)
    {
        location = loc;
    }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've already managed to answer Q1. But for the Q2 still need to find an answer...